# Flutter add items in array which have condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching data from an api, the output of the api is like this:

```
{
    "Categories": [{
            "ID": 1064,
            "Name": "Pizza",
            "Subcategories": [{
                    "ID": 87,
                    "CategoryID": 1064,
                    "CategoryName": "Pizza",
                    "Items": [{
                            "ID": 1195,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"
                            "IsFeatured": true,
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1196,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)"
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1197,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ID": 87,
                    "CategoryID": 1064,
                    "CategoryName": "Pizza",
                    "Items": [{
                            "ID": 1195,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1196,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)"
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1197,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": 1064,
            "Name": "Pizza",
            "Subcategories": [{
                "ID": 87,
                "CategoryID": 1064,
                "CategoryName": "Pizza",
                "Items": [{
                        "ID": 1195,
                        "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"
                        "IsFeatured": true,

                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 1196,
                        "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)"
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 1197,
                        "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "ID": 1084,
            "Name": "beverages",
            "Description": null,
            "Image": null,
            "StatusID": 1,
            "LocationID": 2112,
            "Subcategories": []
        }
    ],
    "description": "Success",
    "status": 1
}
```

By foreach loop i am putting all items arrays in one array like this.

```
  data.forEach((category) {
    if (category['Subcategories'] != null) {
      category['Subcategories'].forEach((subcategory) {
        items['Items'].addAll(subcategory['Items']);
      });
    }
  });
```

its working also fine now i need to do this to the Items which have `"IsFeatured": true,` all items array dont have IsFeatured in array only some have. So what i need to do is just add those Items which have IsFeatured True.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the more functional approaches to accomplish what you are doing. Especially the `map` and `where` functions on Dart's `Iterable`.

Before calling `forEach` in your inner loop you can call `where`. This takes a function (like `forEach` does) that returns either `true` or false`. If the condition is` true` the item remains in the list, otherwise it is filtered out.

Something like this:

```dart
category['Subcategories']
  .where((subcategory) => subcategory.isFeatured)
  .forEach((subcategory) {
        items['Items'].addAll(subcategory['Items']);
      });
```

Edit:
I didn't realize that the property in question is actually one level down, i.e. part of the item.
So combining this with a null-safe access we might get something like:

```dart
  data.forEach((category) {
      category['Subcategories']?.forEach((subcategory) {
        items['Items'].addAll(subcategory['Items'].where((s) => s['IsFeatured'] as bool));
      });
  });
```

You might have to tweak a few things depending on your actual data model and what assumptions you can make about the presence of values. In the example code I assume that `IsFeatured` is never `null`. That might not be the case, so look out for errors there.

Comment: dont know why its showing this errro  Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool' of 'test' on where function

Comment: test function, which is argument of where() must return bool value, so the test will have only two possible verdicts.
also, u could use ?. operator which will really simplfy ur code.

Comment: As @A.Tracevsky said, the function must return a `bool`. And if you pull out a value from your `Map` you get `dynamic`. 
So, if you know that `isFeatured` is a `bool`, you can cast it: `subCategory['isFeatured'] as bool`.

But I'm only now noticing that the `isFeatured` is not a property of the subcategory, but of the item. I will edit my answer accordingly.